# When selecting rows based on a where clause how can I match full words?

Tags: php, mysql, search, sql-like

I am trying to create search functionality for a website.
In MySQL I would like to match words exactly, for example if I have a couple of posts with these titles:

> A day in time

and

> A coming day

and I have the following search string:

```
SELECT title
        FROM posts
        WHERE title LIKE '%in%'
        ORDER BY Date
        DESC
```

It will return both rows because the `LIKE` term `%in%`shows up in both `in` in the first row and  `coming` in the second row.

But I only want it to match whole words, so that only the first row would be returned.

Is this possible?

Comment: [See this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/fulltext-search.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a MySQL word boundary REGEXP:

```
SELECT title
  FROM posts
  WHERE title REGEXP '[[:<:]]in[[:>:]]'
```

From the MySQL docs:

*These markers stand for word boundaries. They match the beginning and end of words, respectively.  A word is a sequence of word characters that is not preceded by or followed by word characters.*

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: Thanks, could you briefly explain what that REGEXP statement does for those that are Manual phobic?

Comment: I updated my answer. Those two markers match the beginning and end of words. REGEXP stands for Regular Expression.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
SELECT title
    FROM posts
    WHERE title LIKE '% in %'
    ORDER BY Date
    DESC
```

If it's a word you are sure there are space before and after the word in question.

Comment: That won't work for titles where it starts or ends with the word "in"

Comment: True! so you can do this LIKE '% in %' or LIKE '%in %' or LIKE '% in%'. I admit it's not the best solution. It's just a way to achieve what he wants. There are probably a much better way.